# Different AppPoolIdentities for App and Reverse Proxy - IIS Out-Of-Process Hosting?

Tags: asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, iis-10, kestrel-http-server, applicationpoolidentity

I am trying to implement the ASP.NET Core out-of-process hosting model.

Previously we had a **Windows Service** running as a **LocalService** user. This service was protected with an **IIS reverse proxy** and **AppPoolIdentity** user.

`client <--> Reverse Proxy (AppPoolIdentity) <--> Windows Service (LocalService)`

Now that the **IIS** - ASP.NET Core Module (w3wp.exe) itself **starts** the ASP.NET Core **Application** (dotnet.exe) on request, **both** run as **LocalService** identities.

`client <--> Reverse Proxy (LocalService) <--> Kestrel Service (LocalService)`

Is this fine, from a security point of view, to configure both, the reverse proxy as well as the app, as LocalService or is it advisable to configure the IIS or the Kestrel server differently?

I couldn't find any information on this topic online. Any kind of help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Local service is not the minimum you can get, so no your current setup is not optimal. There are articles on identity comparison if you use a search engine, but web server security is much bigger a topic than individual questions. Hire a security consultant or you may miss a lot.